# Update state of an object in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to update a state of an object and notify to update the UI accordingly.

For example

```
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

class CounterState {
  int value;
  bool isCompleted;
  CounterState({this.value = 0, this.isCompleted = false});
}

@riverpod
class CounterProvider extends _$CounterProvider {
  @override
  CounterState build() {
    return CounterState;
  }

  void setValue(int newValue) {
    state.value = newValue;
    if (newValue == 1) {
      state.isCompleted = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I use CounterState to contain all the necessary state of for 1 page. As this method doesn't work, and only works if I use this

```
if (newValue == 1) {
      state = CounterState(value: newValue, isCompleted: true);
}
```

As if the state object become more and more complex, I want to keep other variable in the state remain the same, and only update the one I need, for the example above I can use something like this

```
if (___) {
      state = CounterState(value: state.value, isCompleted: true);
}
```

But it is going to be difficult to update the state if CounterState have 10 variables or more.
Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the copyWith method

```
class CounterState {

  int value;
  bool isCompleted;

  CounterState({
    this.value = 0, 
    this.isCompleted = false
  });

  CounterState copyWith({ int? value, bool? isCompleted }) => CounterState(
    value: value ?? this.value,
    isCompleted: isCompleted ?? this.isCompleted
  );
}
```

With that done, you can just do:

```
state = state.copyWith(value: newValue, isCompleted: true, ...);
```

And just specify the fields you would like to update.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good solution for this